# jQuery code failing silently in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a page which works fine in Firefox and Safari on OS X and
Chrome on Windows.

The expected behaviour is that when you hover over one of the blue
boxes an icon will appear to indicate whether or not the box is
editable. If it is editable (pencil icon) then clicking it should
bring up an overlay with an editing box.

In IE8 (and below) clicking the blue boxes does nothing—anyone have
any idea why?

URL: http://www.quis.cc/bmxmusic/

Comment: Rather than pasting links, please create a small, self-contained test case and post that.

Comment: @T.J Crowder whats up with the live url? It is easier to see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is encoding your string in URL encoding.  You may have to escape the # character when the client is using IE or see if it is possible to force IE to use a different encoding for the URL string so that it doesn't cause this problem.  I just tell people to use anything but IE and make my code work on every other browser ;) so I can't tell you exactly how to do this from my own experience... good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that making a $.post request to `page.php#anchor` works fine in most browsers, but in IE it gets encoded to `page.php%23anchor` which causes a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Your $.post is failing in ie with a 404. See below.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/2f62e12490059f29ab92719fba19621f.png))</sub>

Comment: That Fiddler tool is really useful. I hardly ever have to use Windows so it's the kind of thing I wouldn't have otherwise known about. Gonna look into the problem now, thanks!

Comment: there are a few of them - webscarab (java based so x-platform), wireshark etc